# Calling JavaScript for specific page irrespective of whichever theme you select

Tags: pages, headers, wp-head

I recently added a JavaScript file that pulls JSON data and updates the `div` tag on specific page of my WordPress, now to apply the JavaScript file to the page I added to header tag in the theme and secondly this JavaScript is getting called for every page/blog/ URL of my WordPress when I want it to execute only for specific page.

How can I have JavaScript script tag called for the specific page instead of all pages? I do not want to apply it in theme because now I am stuck with the current theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) for the information how to add scripts without editing the HTML.

I assume the script is already registered or you'll add all necessary parameters.

Tied to the particular page ID:

```
if( is_page($page_id) ) { // provide the page ID
    wp_enqueue_script('YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME'); //enqueue the script on success
}
```

Tied to the page slug:

```
$slug = get_post_field( 'post_name', get_post() ); // get the page slug
if('the-very-same-page-slug' == $slug) { // compare the slug against the very same
    wp_enqueue_script('YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME'); //enqueue the script on success
}
```

Tied to the page custom field (preferred):

```
$cf = get_post_field( 'CUSTOM_FIELD_NAME', get_post() ); // get the custom field
if( !empty($cf) ) { // see if the field exists or non-empty
    wp_enqueue_script('YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME'); //enqueue the script on success
}
```

You can create your own plugin to be independent of the theme. See [Plugin Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/) for more.

Comment: When you say register you mean in my php file I should `wp_register_script( 'Access to Home Online', 'http://san.gotdns.ch/function.js', array('jQuery`));` ?

Comment: Yes. Also, you can bypass registering the script by using `wp_enqueue_script()` with additional parameters.